# Adding events to scrollTo plugin for scrolling keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, keyboard, navigation, scroll

I'm trying to add keyboard navigation to a site design and I've been following this [Adding Keyboard Navigation tutorial by Remy Sharp](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/adding-keyboard-navigation/) but I can't seem to adapt it to my needs.

I'd like to add this code to the scrollTo plugin so when the user clicks the up or down keys the page will scroll to the next or previous section.

This is the code that Remy goes over:

```
$(window).keyup(function (event) { 

            if(event.keyCode == 40) { //down key
            $('#nav-bar #nav li.current').parent().prev().find('a').click();    
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38) { //up key
              $('#nav-bar #nav li.current').parent().next().find('a').click()
            }
        });
```

I've adapted it for my HTML mark up and I'm going for the up and down arrow keys as he was going for the left and right but apart from that it's pretty much the same as his. In his version he's added it to a plugin called codaSlider and I was wondering if it was possible to add it to the [scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) that I have and if anyone has any ideas on how to do that?

Here's his completed code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();

  $('body').keyup(function (event) {
    var direction = null;

    // handle cursor keys
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
      // slide left
      direction = 'prev';
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
      // slide right
      direction = 'next';
    }

    if (direction != null) {
      $('ul a.current').parent()[direction]().find('a').click();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of what you really want to do but here is an example with keyboardJS and scrollTo jquery plugin :

http://jsfiddle.net/Raildecom/TwJAM/

Tell me if it fits your needs !

**Edit :**

Here is a new version with throttling : http://jsfiddle.net/Raildecom/TwJAM/4/

You can tweak two params :

```
//Handle keyDown events throttling
//Will execute one event every 2sec when the user hold the key
var throttleKeyDown = 2000;

//Handle KeyUp events throttling
//Will wait 0.3sec after the user release the key to avoid "double click" effect
var throttleKeyUp = 300;

//Parent node. Doesn't have to be ul
var node = $('ul');
```

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, Sorry i pushed enter by mistake on my last comment. Thank you for your response. That's amazing it's pretty much exactly what i'm looking for, i haven't heard of keyboardJS before (even after 2 days of searching for a solution). The only problem is if the user double clicks the arrow key twice by mistake it jumps around a little bit and it sometimes doesn't register the scroll function and just scrolls like the default browser scroll, but apart from that it's spot on. Thank you for sharing. I'd still be interested in hearing if there's any other solutions out there.

Comment: No problem :) I edited my code. Tell me if it works better now

Comment: Thank you so very much for taking the time to do that, Emmanuel. I really appreciate it.  I really hope i'm not pushing my luck here but how easy would it be to implement the left and right keys as well?  For example if i pushed the right key the page would scroll down and the left key would scroll up?

Comment: Really easy ! With keyboardJS you can bind with multiple keys like this : "down, right" / "up, left". You can also create combo like this : "a+b"

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if you have resolved the issue :)

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, I'm having some difficulty with the script from yesterday and i was wondering if i could mail you the link for you to have a look at? I know what the problem is but i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Just a point, but wouldn't such discussions be better placed here? For all to see and learn from? :)

Comment: Hi Stuart ! Actually the discussion stops here... But if you or Cameron are having a bad time with that code, please ask me here :)